# Linq Query join between 2 lists

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

Firstly, I have a list of AD users acquired from an AD parsing dll. This has 2 properties that I am interested in: Phone# and EmailID. (lets call it var EmployeeAD)

Secondly, I have a list of of users with properties such as fullname, employeeID, username, etc etc (doesn't contain phone# and emailID).

```
    List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
    using (var ctx = new hr_employeeEntities())
    {
        var emps = (from x in ctx.F_Emp
                    join y in ctx.HR_EMPL_VW on (x.employee_id).ToString() equals y.EMPLID
                    where x.employment_status == "A"
                    select new{ x, y }).ToList();

        //PSFT_Employee is an inherited class of the abstract class Employee //
        employees = emps.Select(x => (new PSFT_Employee
        {
            employee_id = x.x.employee_id,
            full_name = x.x.employee_name,
            username = x.y.OPRID,
            date_of_birth = x.x.date_of_birth,                                       
            date_of_hire = x.x.original_hire_date,

            phone = ,
            email = x.x. ,
            }) as Employee).ToList();
         }

    return employees;
```

I need to be able to join the first list of AD users (based on key - OPRID) with the second list of emps...such that I can populated the employees object with phone # and email for each employee.

Something like :-

```
emps.Foreach( // for each employee in emps, join with user in employeeAD based on common OPRID. Then extract phone# and email for that user and populate in emps list//)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I have the requirement right, but are you looking for a second join?

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();
using (var ctx = new hr_employeeEntities())
{
    var emps = (from x in ctx.F_Emp
                join y in ctx.HR_EMPL_VW on (x.employee_id).ToString() equals y.EMPLID
                where x.employment_status == "A"
                select new{ x, y }).ToList();

    //PSFT_Employee is an inherited class of the abstract class Employee //
    employees = emps.Join(
        users,//don't know what you have for this
        emp => emp.OPRID,
        user => user.OPRID,

        (u, e) => new { u, e })     
    .Select(a => (new PSFT_Employee
    {
        employee_id = a.u.x.employee_id,
        full_name = a.u.x.employee_name,
        username = a.u.y.OPRID,
        date_of_birth = a.u.x.date_of_birth,
        date_of_hire = a.u.x.original_hire_date,
        phone = a.e.phone,
        email = a.e.email,
        }) as Employee).ToList();
     }

return employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't say so, I assume that every EmployeeAd has an identifying Id. So your EmployeeAd will look like:

```
class EmployeeAd
{
    public int Id {get; set;} // primary key
    public string PhoneNr {get; set;}
    public string Email {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

The actual types of the properties is not important. What is important is that the property type of Id equals the property type of the Emplyee Id in the 2nd list.

If you know that every Employee has an EmployeeAd, you can use a simple (inner) join. You can also use this if you don't want employees without EployeeAds:

```
var joinedEmployess = dbConext.Employees.Join(  // join Employees
    dbContext.EmployeeAdds,                     // with EmployeeAds
    employee => employee.Id,                    // from every Employee take the Id
    employeeAd => employeeAd.Id,                // from every EmployeeAd take the Id

    (employee, employeeAd) => new PSFT_Employee() // when they match make one new
    {
        // fill the Employee properties you plan to use
        Id = employee.Id,
        Name = employee.Name,
        ...

        // fill the PhoneNr and Email:
        PhoneNr = employeeAd.PhoneNr,
        Email = employeeAd.Email,
    });
```